# Проверка, на клик по элементe $('menu')

Tags: jquery, dom

Нужна проверка , если был клик на элементе $('menu'). тогда функция не должна срабатываться. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- заводим булеву переменную, например `var isMenuClicked =  false;`
- вешаем слушателя события `click` на элемент
- при клике делаем `isMenuClicked  = true`
- в начале отслеживаемой функции пишем `if (isMenuClicked) return;`
- всё

Comment: Спасибо Большое!С наступающим!